# How to fix clip-path altering the z-index stacking order of page?

Tags: html, css, position, z-index, clip-path

https://jsfiddle.net/9gqbne6j/1/

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="row-inner">
    <div class="row-background"><div class="row-background-inner">
    
    </div></div>
    <div class="row-content">
    <section class="first-section">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Circle-icons-flame.svg/1024px-Circle-icons-flame.svg.png" class="icon">
      <h2 class="section-heading">
      Some Heading
      </h2>
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ullamcorper justo a neque mollis iaculis.
      </p>
      <button class="read-more">Read More</button>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBpZD0iTGF5ZXJfMSIgZGF0YS1uYW1lPSJMYXllciAxIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAzMjAuNSA2MDQwLjEiPjxkZWZzPjxzdHlsZT4uY2xzLTF7ZmlsbDojMjMxZjIwO29wYWNpdHk6MC43O308L3N0eWxlPjwvZGVmcz48cG9seWdvbiBjbGFzcz0iY2xzLTEiIHBvaW50cz0iMzIwLjUgMjQ0OC45MiAwIDYwNDAuMSAwIDYwNDAuMSAwIDAgMzIwLjUgMjQ0OC45MiIvPjwvc3ZnPg==);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 29.66%;
  background-position: right 3% top 40%;
}

.row-inner {
  position: relative;
  clip-path: polygon(-38% 50%,128% 110%,128% -10%)
}

.row-background-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url(https://i0.wp.com/www.wagpets.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/pembroke-welsh-corgi-appearance-and-vital-stats.jpeg?resize=1429%2C956&ssl=1);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.row-content {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.first-section {
    padding: 2em 1em;
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: column;
   align-items: center;
   max-width: 33%;
   z-index: 9;
}

.section-heading {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.read-more {
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  background-color: steelblue;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
}
```

Above is a minimal example of the issue I'm trying to fix. It's pulled from a much larger page, so I was hoping it'd be possible to fix via CSS rather than completely reorganising the DOM.

So, the .row-inner element has a clip-path on it. If the clip-path is enabled, then the .first-section text appears underneath the body::after background, but if the clip-path is disabled, then the text appears above the body::after background.

Is there a way to get the .first-section to appear above the body::after background with clip-path still enabled?

I've read from previous questions that it has something to do with clip-path altering the render order of the elements, but I couldn't find a solution for the issue in this case that I haven't tried already.

If it's not possible to fix via CSS alone, what would be the most minimal way to re-order the DOM to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: I gave you the answer. Is this the result you wanted?

Comment: Yesh. I've marked it as the accepted answer now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @floodlitworld, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule `clip-path` needs to be assigned to **more child** element.

Specify this rule for `.row-background-inner` by removing it from `.row-inner`.

```css
html,
body {
    background-color: grey;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBpZD0iTGF5ZXJfMSIgZGF0YS1uYW1lPSJMYXllciAxIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAzMjAuNSA2MDQwLjEiPjxkZWZzPjxzdHlsZT4uY2xzLTF7ZmlsbDojMjMxZjIwO29wYWNpdHk6MC43O308L3N0eWxlPjwvZGVmcz48cG9seWdvbiBjbGFzcz0iY2xzLTEiIHBvaW50cz0iMzIwLjUgMjQ0OC45MiAwIDYwNDAuMSAwIDYwNDAuMSAwIDAgMzIwLjUgMjQ0OC45MiIvPjwvc3ZnPg==);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 29.66%;
    background-position: right 3% top 40%;
}

.row-inner {
    position: relative;
    /*clip-path: polygon(-38% 50%,128% 110%,128% -10%);*/
}

.row-background-inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-image: url(https://i0.wp.com/www.wagpets.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/pembroke-welsh-corgi-appearance-and-vital-stats.jpeg?resize=1429%2C956&ssl=1);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    clip-path: polygon(-38% 50%, 128% 110%, 128% -10%);
}

.row-content {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.first-section {
    padding: 2em 1em;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 33%;
    z-index: 9;
}

.section-heading {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.read-more {
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    background-color: steelblue;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="row-inner">
        <div class="row-background"><div class="row-background-inner"></div></div>
        <div class="row-content">
            <section class="first-section">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4a/Circle-icons-flame.svg/1024px-Circle-icons-flame.svg.png" class="icon" />
                <h2 class="section-heading">
                    Some Heading
                </h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ullamcorper justo a neque mollis iaculis.
                </p>
                <button class="read-more">Read More</button>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```